# Checked listitem radiobutton duplicate when scrolling

Tags: java, android, duplicates

Whenever I check a radiobutton inside a listItem, and start scrolling down the listItem suddenly duplicates and appears beneath the list. And sometimes it disappears from the top and is only displayed on the bottom.

Here is my adapter method.

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    
    public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] strings) {
        super(context, -1, -1, strings);
    } 
    
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LinearLayout listLayout = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            
        //Make the listLayout
        listLayout = new LinearLayout(Bouw_onderdeel.this);
        listLayout.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        listLayout.setId(5000);
        listLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        
        //Make the Radiogroup.
        RadioGroup rbg = new RadioGroup(Bouw_onderdeel.this);
        rbg.setId(3927);
        rbg.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);    
        rbg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
        {
            
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                
            }
        });
        //Make the list Items containing radiobuttons en textviews.
        TextView listText = new TextView(Bouw_onderdeel.this);
        listText.setId(5001);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    RadioButton rbtn = new RadioButton (Bouw_onderdeel.this);
                    rbg.addView(rbtn);
        }       
        //Add them to the listlayout.
        listLayout.addView(rbg);
        listLayout.addView(listText);

        listText.setText(super.getItem(position));

        convertView = listLayout;
        convertView.setTag(listLayout);
        } else{
        listLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.getTag();
        }
        
    return listLayout;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You return existing convertView without setting actual selection.
In onCheckedChanged method you have to store new selection state for radio buttons and use it when building view in getView() method

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private int[] selections;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] strings) {
        super(context, -1, -1, strings);
        selections = new int[strings.length];
    } 

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ... 
        rbg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                selections[position] = checkedId;
            }
        });
        ...
        rbg.check(selections[position]);
        return listLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your method but the "selections[position] = checkedId;" doesn't seem to work unless int position is final.

Comment: make it final, why not?

Answer (score 0):

you are not using view holder class...that's why you are facing this problem...follow this tutorial:

```
   [http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-listview-optimizations]
```

Answer (score 0):

This don't make sense :

```
convertView = listLayout;
convertView.setTag(listLayout);
...
listLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.getTag();
```

When the `convertView!=null` : you must update the data in it. If you return it 'as is' : it will be displayed 'as is' (i.e. with the same data as the data of the previous position of the convertView)

Just to clarify the concept of `convertView` :

If the `convertView` is not null : it is because Android give a chance to re-use a view that was preously used in your listView but is now out of the screen. So you don't have to re-create the view from scratch and all you have to do is updating the data according the new `position` of the convertView

---

Try this :

```
((TextView)convertView.findViewById(5001)).setText(super.getItem(position));
```

Comment: I'm still new to android/java so how would one fix this?

Comment: I read it thanks for the help so far! But the same problem occurs. I'll show you my example.

The first image is when I scroll down you can see the last one is duplicated.

The second one is when I scroll back up, and the third one is when I scroll down again. http://i.imgur.com/GKOgHJS.png